# Use Fabric's to get a shell with context managers like 'prefix' and 'cd' applied?

Tags: python, fabric

How can I get an interactive shell that's aware of any of Fabric's context managers that have been applied?

For example, I'd expect that this would open a shell in `/tmp/` with a virtualenv active:

```
with cd("/tmp/"):
    with prefix("source virtualenv/bin/activate"):
        open_shell()
```

But this doesn't — it just opens a normal login shell.

Using `run("bash")` gets half way there, but no `PS1` is set, and all lines are prefixed with Fabric's `[user@host] out: …`.

PS: Yes, I know that I could use `open_shell(command="cd /tmp/; source …")`, but I want a general solution.

Answer (score 0):

Fabric's `open_shell` function does not support this.

If you want that, you may want to write your own wrapper to `open_shell` that first examines `env.cwd` and `env.command_prefixes` in order to generate the `command` that you would then pass to `open_shell`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my utility for it:

```
def smart_shell(command=''):
    env_commands = "cd '%s'; %s" % (env.cwd, " && ".join(env.command_prefixes))
    open_shell('%s; %s' % (env_commands, command))

# Usage
with cd('/tmp/'), prefix("source virtualenv/bin/activate"):
    smart_shell('./manage.py shell')
```

Comment: By typing them in and hitting Enter. If you mean automatically, then you shouldn't open shell and just use `run()` instead.

Comment: well i experienced a similar issue and reported in ,http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37402849/fabric-connect-to-machines-with-wierd-prompts?noredirect=1#comment62351264_37402849