# fabric - connect to machines with wierd prompts

Tags: python, virtual-machine, prompt, paramiko, fabric

Since fabric is based on paramiko, is there any API to connect to virtual appliance with ssh-process having weird interactive shells ?

How can fabric interact with processes acting as such shells.

e.g.
VM acting as switch having prompt 'switch-> ' when login is done over ssh. fabfile.py need to feed commands thereafter. once such command is to deploy images over tftpboots. The VM provides both telnet/ssh interface with user/password)

I tried below code, but it does not work -

```
 @task
 taskA():
      with settings(prompts={'switch-> ' : 'bringkickstart img.bin' }):
          run('save image')
```

Comment: does the VM have bash?

Comment: unfortunately no. But some tcsh shell to handle switch like commands (prompt as 'switch-> ').

Comment: by default fabric assumes that remote system has bash under `/bin`; you may try to set `env.shell = '/bin/tcsh'` (or whatever the path is). Also I'd give a try to run it without shell (`run('save image', shell=False)`). I wouldn't worry so much about the prompt if that's the first thing you get once connected.